# MySQL LIKE search not working when there are unicode characters used as Search term

Tags: mysql, unicode, utf-8, special-characters, sql-like

I have a table column in MYSQL which is VARCHAR(3000)

And I am doing a LIKE search like this

```
SELECT * FROM employee where NAME LIKE N'%$search_term%'
```

`search_term` can be any character and unicode too.

Now I have 3 records with descriptions like this respectively. They are English and Unicode characters mixed.

```
1) 44T8aJeYzU헾⼁놓좟뇘눍㼉㺿䦘ꑷꜺ麂蕟Ỻ壟Ⴡ


2) RHuLKzk4KH헾⼁놓좟뇘눍㼉㺿䦘ꑷꜺ麂蕟Ỻ壟ჁacnT3PvSQy


3) 헾⼁놓좟뇘눍㼉㺿䦘ꑷꜺ麂蕟Ỻ壟ჁZanjmxznnP
```

and my search term is

```
   헾⼁놓좟뇘눍㼉㺿䦘ꑷꜺ麂蕟ỻ壟ⴡ
```

I was supposed to get 3 records (If I copy these values to a text editor for that search_term, I get 3 matches )
but I get empty records.

the collation of the column is `utf8_general_ci` and MySQL version is 5.7.23

Is this the limitations of MySQL LIKE Search ?

Comment: And when you query your DB directly with `SELECT column FROM employee WHERE name LIKE '%헾⼁놓좟뇘눍㼉㺿䦘ꑷꜺ麂蕟ỻ壟ⴡ%';`? If that works then your program logic or handing over the encoding is wrong. Are you sure you need the `N` as a [literal prefix](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-literals.html)?

Comment: If I query in database directly, I get empty results which means it has got something to do with MySQL database itself

Comment: I doubt that and suspect a wrong encoding during the input. Query `SELECT hex( 'Ꜻ' );` - in UTF-8 it should return 'EA9CBAEF9C9CEEBA90' (3 bytes per character). Try that function then on your table column and check if the results differ (which would indicate a non-UTF-8 encoding). When connecting to the DB, set the encoding to `utf8mb4` instead of `utf8`.

Comment: Check the connection.  It needs to specify utf8, too.

Answer (score 0):

this is resolved by setting

```
--character-set-server=utf8mb4 --collation-server=utf8mb4_unicode_ci
```

in the docker-compose.yml